# Showing totals as per certain conditions

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to show totals depending on certain criteria's. Let me show my db structure.

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ tender_id ║ sup_name  ║ ifmain ║ total ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║    400    ║  Suppl1   ║  Yes   ║ 2000  ║
║  2 ║    400    ║  Suppl2   ║  Yes   ║ 2500  ║
║  3 ║    400    ║  Suppl1   ║  No    ║ 2000  ║
║  4 ║    400    ║  Suppl3   ║  No    ║ 2900  ║
║  5 ║    400    ║  Suppl1   ║  Yes   ║ 3100  ║
║  6 ║    402    ║  Suppl2   ║  Yes   ║ 877   ║
║  7 ║    402    ║  Suppl3   ║  No    ║ 9888  ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Now i need to find the sum of total by tender_id and sup_name and ifmain and show totals. Example I need to show the totals where tender_id=400 and sup_name=Supl1 and ifmain=Yes or Ifmain=No. I need to show the ifMain=Yes and ifMain=No totals separately. How can I achieve that.

I tried the below query. its working as per tender_id, now I need to add a condition for sup_name also. How will I do that:

```
select tender_id, SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'Yes' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS maintotal, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'No' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS subtotal from
comparitive_st_sup where tender_id='400'
```

Comment: show an example of the output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, just add grouping:

```
select tender_id, 
       sup_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'Yes' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS maintotal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'No' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS subtotal 
from comparitive_st_sup
group by tender_id, sup_name
```

Comment: Thank you.. :) that's a small mistake I made.